# Primary Key for an OAuth Consumer Model

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oauth, oauth-2.0

All my life I've been using **autoincrement primary key** values for my entities. That is, an `int` primary key.

Even now, when I read discussions about what to use as primary key, the winning group is always the one that supports `int` keys.

But, let's suppose I want to store a list of consumers that use my web service. OAuth customers, to be specific.

A `consumerId` and `consumerSecret` would be stored, along with other relevant information.

Now, the `consumerId` will be generated when the user registers as a new consumer. This `id` is supposed to be **unique**.

Is there an advantage of using an `int` primary key in this case? In fact, the consumers will provide me with their `id` when signing in, and not their `int primary key`. So the queries will use this `id` for the searching.

Also as an important note, this `id` will have a fixed length of 64 characters, so indexing should be better than if using `nvarchar`.

What are the advantages and disafvantages of usin an `nchar` primary key?

**PS**: I am using Microsoft SQL Server as the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Non-numeric primary keys come with added overheads.

-->>> While performing a search on this table, the engine would take *little* longer time in comparing against the SARG.

-->>> During any DML(Insert, Update, Delete), the entire tree might need to be shuffled by the engine to keep it balanced, and due to the large data types juggling, it might lead to degraded performance.

**BUT** in your case, as you said, searches are going to be on the `ConsumerID`, it does make sense to have this column indexed. Non Clustered index will only lead to increased lookups.

The best bet I see is to not go for indexes at all but instead using the [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) functionality to search for the `ConsumerID` token.